# Phonegap: How do i build for the web?

Tags: web, cordova

So much documentation for getting phonegap to work on various mobile platforms, but I can't find a lick about how to get it to work for the web.

I'm already signed up on phonegap build as well, if that helps at all.

How do I test my app for the web? Or does Phonegap ironically not support the web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhoneGap does *not* support *the web*. PhoneGap **extends** the web.

If you want to create a mobile website, just create a mobile website. PhoneGap was created to extend the browser, because of its limitations.

Phonegap / Cordova is a **native** application wrapper, that display HTML-content within a Browser-Control.

The Cordova API calls **native** functions, to extends the browser capabilities.

So what is your question about?

- Testing JavaScript Applications? -> Jasmine or [QUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUnit)
- Deploying a WebApllication? -> Apache httpd, node.js or niginx

Comment: Thanks for the info!
I was initially under the impression that with Phonegap, you would build a fully functional web app, then deploy it to any phone.
I suppose that would be challenging considering how different the APIs are for things like the camera, especially considering the HTML5 specs for devices are still very young and little supported when Phonegap came out.

Comment: If you're curious about my dilemma. My background is web development and I think I share that with a lot of programmers and I need an easy environment for a hackathon coming up, that allows the programmers to program for iOS and other mobile devices.

The problem I came up to was that the iOS simulator doesn't use the devices camera as a test and in order to use a device as a test device you need a developer account with Apple, which I doubt most developers have, so we're sorta up a creek on it.

Comment: What I'm going to have to do is have the developer write an HTML5 app for now, then I'll personally convert it to Phonegap later, considering the only code changes should be for the camera.

Regardless, you answered my question of whether Phonegap supports the web, and it renders the rest of my questions moot. Thanks :).

Comment: If you want to build an iOS App you will need an apple-account. Without account it is impossible to deploy to a device or into the store.

Comment: The Cameraplugin became nearly useless for iOS, because a <input type=file /> will create a button that opens the camera or the galery.

Comment: oh really? I'll try that Christian.